# upload large file size(larger than 1048MB) from php using xampp and mysql

Tags: large-file-upload

I have a web application using in a local network. I made it by(php, html, mysql) and using xampp to share it in a local network, my problem is that I can't upload larger than **1GB** file to database because I want to upload larger than **3GB** files. I use **move_uploaded_file ()** to move file to a directory in source folders. It not moves whoever I make changes to **php.ini** file like this

memory_limit=5000M
php_value post_max_size 5000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 6000M
Max_upload_time 6000
Max_execution_time 6000

I try these solutions many times but the problem is not solved hence became tired.
Please show me to solve the problem 
Thanks

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: Warning: POST Content-Length of 2147483647 bytes exceeds the limit of 947912704 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1):

try to fix your code with this on php.ini :

```
upload_max_filesize=6000M
post_max_size=5000M
max_execution_time=6000
max_input_time=6000
```

Don't forget to restart your xampp after change the code. Good Luck :)